# Join points to a line with minimal distance

Tags: shapely, geopandas

I have a point cloud (x,y) in a random order.

Say `sorted([(1, 1), (2, 2), (0, 0), (4, 4), (3, 3)])`. Is there an easy way to connect them to a simple line like `((0,0),(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4))` doing this "smart" reordering (shortest path)?

Comment: For the example data, you could first sort the coordinates as tuples (eg `sorted([(1, 1), (2, 2), (0, 0), (4, 4), (3, 3)])` will do the correct thing in python), but the question is if your actual data has a similar 'simple' sorting logic ? (sorting first on x then on y).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shortest line going through a set of points is often called the **travelling sales rep problem**, for which the standard approach is **simulated annealling**.  It's certainly much trickier than `sorted(list)` but whether it's easy or not depends on a) how fussy your application is and b) how much coding experience you have.  It can be done in about 100 lines of code as you see below.

On your sample `anneal([(1, 1), (2, 2), (0, 0), (4, 4), (3, 3)])`
gives either `[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4)]` or 
`[(4, 4), (3, 3), (2, 2), (1, 1), (0, 0)]` at random, as both are optimal.

The idea is what route of sales visits to a given list of cities uses the least petrol -- the travelling sales rep.  "Annealling" comes by analogy with the process of slowly cooling metals to give them springiness.

It gives results where the path is "probably close to optimal".  How close can be very difficult to establish, but the results are usually good.  For a test set of 20 random points on a 100 x 100 grid, results look like this::

[image: Travelling sales rep problem diagrams]

On the left is the closed path, where the last point joins to the first; on the right is open path.
The grey lines are the original, unordered list; the yellow ones are the result of the annealling; green dot is starting point, red is last.
In some cases the open and closed path results are very different, in this case they're very similar (open path solution omits longest segment, with some small random variation in the top left).

A decent explanation is in *Numerical Recipes in C*,
Press, Flannery, Teukolsky, Vetterling, Cambridge University Press 1988, ISBN 0-521-35465-X, p345.  But as the literature on the subject is enormous, you'll easily find others.

The basic idea is:

- define a *state*, in this case an ordering of the points
- define a *cost* function, in this case the length of the line (sum of pythagorus distances, can be closed path or open depending on your need) *or any other arbitrary metric whatsoever*
- define some *transformations*, of which the following are typical:

  - "reverse a section", so rev(0, 3, [a, **b, c, d**, e]) -> [a, **d, c, b**, e]
  - "cut a section", so cut(0, 3, [a, **b, c, d**, e]) -> [**b, c, d**, e, a]

The algorithm then repeatedly

- define a starting temperature *t*, perhaps 0.5
- try the following *k* times, perhaps 100:

  - chooses an transformation at random (*rev* or *cut*, on a random portion of the list)
  - work out the cost of the change ie Δc = cost(transformation(list)) - cost(list); nb Δc is negative if the change is good, as it means the cost is going down
  - if cost is going down, keep this transformation
  - even if the cost is going up, keep the transformation if a random value is smaller than an exponentially decreasing calculation based on the current temperature.  This is the clever bit of the "metropolitan" algorithm which makes it annealling: we take the transformation if *e<sup>-Δc/t</sup>* is below a random number (0 to 1).
- reduce the temperature by a cooling factor, perhaps 0.9
- quit after a specified number of coolings, perhaps 100

Here's a coding in python, intended to be easy to understand rather than efficient.  The magic numbers (starting temperature, cooling factor, number of iterations) are found by experiment.  This coding in python is basically exactly that of the C version in the *Numerical Recipes* book.  (Though there they carefully work out the benefit of the change before doing it, which is an important optimisation in the code as it much reduces memory usage and also makes the decision unit time rather than dependent on the length of the list of points.)

```
def anneal(points, t=0.5, chillfactor=0.9, nchill=100, ngood=False, nstep=False):
  npoints = len(points)
  if ngood == False:
    ngood = 10 * npoints
  if nstep == False:
    nstep = 10 * npoints
  chill = 0
  while chill < nchill:
    pl = pathlen(points);
    changes = 0
    step = 0
    while step < nstep:
      p1 = random.randint(0, npoints)
      p2 = random.randint(0, npoints)
      if p1 > p2:
        p1, p2 = p2, p1
      part1 = points[:p1]
      part2 = points[p1:p2+1]
      part3 = points[p2+1:]
     if random.randint(0, 1):
        # a cut operation: a[bcd]e => bcdea
        poss = part3
        poss.extend(part2)
        poss.extend(part1)
      else:
        # a rev operation: a[bcd]e => adcbe
        part2.reverse()
        poss = part1
        poss.extend(part2)
        poss.extend(part3)
      delta = pathlen(poss) - pathlen(points)
      if delta < 0:
        points = poss
        changes += 1

      # following is the clever piece: exponentially decreasing probability of taking big changes
      elif random.random() < math.exp(-delta / t):
        points = poss
        changes += 1

      if changes >= ngood:
        break
      step += 1

    t *= chillfactor
    chill += 1

    if changes == 0:
      break
  return points
```

Here's the test case which made the diagrams at the top:

```
random.seed(0) # for reproducible results
p20 = [(10, 12), (78, 80), (74, 78), (17,  7), (89, 15),
       ( 2, 80), (74, 96), ( 3, 31), (28, 45), (74, 89),
       (13, 92), (59, 87), (54, 34), (73, 52), (21, 69),
       (56, 30), (80, 72), (17, 16), (34, 18), (30, 99)]
min20 = anneal(p20)
print pathlen(p20), pathlen(min20)
print min20
```

The original closed path length is 1249.069
The resulting path len is 371.757

```
[(59, 87), (74, 96), (74, 89), (78, 80), (74, 78),
 (80, 72), (73, 52), (89, 15), (56, 30), (54, 34),
 (34, 18), (17, 16), (17,  7), (10, 12), ( 3, 31),
 (28, 45), (21, 69), ( 2, 80), (13, 92), (30, 99)]
```

The example uses a `pathlen()` function to give the cost of the path.  You define this to be open or closed depending on your problem.  (ie, do you add in the distance from the first point to the last point).  Although the tests I did on random points usually gave paths with no crossings, you need to define it in your `pathlen` if you want to prevent it -- ie, give a very high cost to paths which have crossings.

Related algorithms to travelling sales rep are the point-in-polygon problem (for detecting self-intersecting polygons) and the convex hull problem, which finds the rubber-band path around a point cloud.

Comment: Thanks so much! :-) I know the algorithm but just did not see the forest for the trees to recognize the *travelling salesman* problem...